# Como encontrar subsequências de um vetor dado, excluindo posições dadas?

Tags: python, array, algoritmo

Dado o vetor v:

```
[7 , 8 , 30 , -2 , 9]
```

E o vetor rem, que contém, em ordem crescente, as posições removidas:

```
[1 , 4]
```

É necessário fazer uma função seq(rem,n) (onde n é o número de elementos do vetor) que retornará o início e o fim de cada uma das subsequências que não contém as posições removidas:

```
[(0,0) , (2,3)]
```

Tentei começar com alguns casos especiais:

```
if(len(r) == 0):
    return [(0,n-1)]
elif(len(r) == 1):
    if(r[0] == 0):
      return [(1,n-1)]
    elif(r[0] == n -1):
      return [(0, n-2)]
    else:
      return [(0, r[0]-1), (r[0]+1, n-1)]
```

Depois os casos gerais:

```
sequencias = []
if(r[0] == 0):
    if(r[1] != 1):
      sequencias.append((1, r[1]-1))
    elif(r[1] == 1 and len(r) ==2):
      sequencias.append((r[1]+1 , n-1))
      return sequencias
else:
    if(r[1] - r[0] > 1):
      sequencias.append((r[0]+1 , r[1]-1))

  
for i in range(1,len(r)-1):
    if(r[i+1] - r[i]  > 1):
      sequencias.append((r[i]+1 , r[i+1]-1))


  return sequencias
```

Comment: Olá Matheus, seria legal você mostrar para a gente o que vc tentou

Comment: @Lucas coloquei algumas coisas do código, mas receio que esteja incompleto.